# C Heap Environment variable

Tags: c, environment-variables, heap-memory

Is there an environment variable in c which stores the heap word size, or at least a variable which stores the type of system ?
For example in 64 bit system would be 8(bytes) and in 32 bit would be 4(bytes)

Comment: C does not define *any* environment variables.  Are you thinking of preprocessor macros?

Comment: In any case, I suspect that this is an XY problem.  For what purpose do you want the information?  Or perhaps you can explain what "heap word size" means to you, especially as distinguished from simply "word size"?

Comment: If you meant to detect if system is 32 or 64 bits, `sizeof(void *)` would be a good int, pointers always have the same size. I think memory addresses (unlike values), can't be sent through address bus in parts, they have to be sent as a whole, so there's no way for a 32 bits computer to handle a 64 bit address (except if that address is sent as a value, ie in a pointer). Not quite sure for last sentence, so below comments will correct me if needed. Your system may store 64 bits addresses if it's 32 bits system, but to access this address you'd need it to be a 64 bits.

Comment: Not quite sure for above comment, so below one will correct me if needed.
Also, some compilers make this available at compile time: `#if __x86_64__` with GCC, check with the one you're using.

Comment: @AR7CORE: The C standard does not require all pointers to be the same size. It is common on current general-purpose systems but is not universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that 64 bit systems can execute 32 bit binaries, in this case, sizeof(void *), sizeof(int), ... will be 4, even on 64 bit system.

You can get some additional mileage using the uname system call (see uname -m). For Intel, it will be x86_64 (64), or i686 (for 32). If you need a solution for Intel only, this can work. You can extend this to other processor (arm, etc.)  but you will need to code each platform that you code may run on. See "machine" in: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html

To make things more complex, you might be running under 32 bit operating system, which runs under 64 bit processor (or some virtualized environment). In those cases, uname will report on the operating system, not on the processor. Not clear which one you are looking for.